# Drag and Drop the images into the Basket

Tags: javascript, html

I can Drag and drop  the colored boxes into the baskets But I m unable to drag and drop the  images into the Basket.

Here is a Script

```
<script type = "text/javascript" > function dragStart(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.getAttribute('id'));
    ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ev.target, 0, 0);
    return true;
}

function dragEnter(ev) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return true;
}

function dragOver(ev) {
    return false;
}

function dragDrop(ev) {
    var src = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(src));
    ev.stopPropagation();
    return false;
} </script>
```

Here is a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bloodviper9000/2j2a3fr5/)**

Comment: Its working in the fiddle link you provided

Comment: I can drag and drop the Colored boxes but I m unable to drag and drop the Images

Comment: Provide an unique ID to image tags . this solves issue. since you are referencing the image which is not known to the DOM as a unique element. if u would have seen the console . u may have got it `Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I've done setting the images as Div background.

As like,

```
<div id="image1" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)" style="height: 50px;width: 50px;  background: url('http://www.chicmags.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/10-Fruits-for-Hair-Growth-50x50.png');" >
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/2j2a3fr5/6/)**